# Using multiple instances of chrome simultaneously

Tags: google-chrome, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make two different Google Chrome profiles?](https://superuser.com/questions/361743/how-do-i-make-two-different-google-chrome-profiles)

I want to be able to use two instances of the latest version of Chrome simultaneously, and I want each to have it's own settings - bookmarks, cookies, extensions etc. and if possible even it's own different dock icon :)

Having another browser window with these capabilities in the same instance is also a possibility.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: ^ Not sure... the differences are 1.I'm on a mac 2.I want to run the two instances side by side and not have to switch between them.

Answer (score 1):

Run Chrome and [Chrome Canary](http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs)

Comment: Keep in mind that Canary is the dev channel. It may have stability issues.

Comment: Sidesteps the question really...

Comment: he could run a linux VM... then use x forwarding to get a separate instance from the linux system but that seems overkill. Different channels is the supported way to run two instances at once it seems.

Comment: seems icky to do it that way.

Comment: I'd love to see a better answer, naturally, but this is the best i can think of ;p

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but have you tried running it as a different user?

It does not have to be an administrator, any account that can run chrome will do.

Then right-click Chrome's Shortcut, select "Run as..." and choose the other user. It should run the program with different settings (stored on the other user's "Documents and Settings" folder).

You can then prepend 'runas /user:otherUser' on the shortcut to have all this happen automatically.

I did this with Dropbox and it worked wonders.

[edit]

Sorry I didn't realise you were on OS X, not sure if there's some way to play around with user accounts on Lion...